# Passing a temporary struct value to function works on Mac but not Windows

Tags: c++, visual-c++, clang

I was porting over my game to Windows from Mac when I encountered an issue passing `SDL_Rect`s to a few functions.  The following is some pseudocode to represent my problem:

```
void someFunction(SDL_Rect rect)
{
  // Does something
}

someFunction((SDL_Rect) {0, 0, 10, 10});
```

Whenever I do something like the above, Visual Studio saya it is an error.  It works just fine in Xcode, and doesn't seem to be something that would be platform-specific, seeing as its just aggregate initialization, so can someone explain why?

Comment: Do you have VS set to C++17?

Comment: You're not creating a temporary `SDL_rect`, not really. You're creating something else (and if I knew for sure what I'd be making an answer) and casting it to an `SDL_rect`.  `someFunction(SDL_Rect {0, 0, 10, 10});` would make a temporary.

Comment: If VS says it was an error, it would be helpful to show that error in your question.

Comment: @user4581301 Possibly a _functional cast expression_?

Comment: @Ron Could be more magic going on in the background. When I compile for C++17 with gcc 8.3 `-pedantic` emits the warning *ISO C++ forbids compound-literals*, so I assume we got a compound-literal. Since pedantic says it's not kosher, I'm jumping to the conclusion that it's something from C99 and MSVS didn't support it. https://godbolt.org/z/tFsV4H

Comment: [Docs for compound literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal). Did show up in C99, I don't see any signs of C++ Standard support, and the usage example contains a justified `goto` statement. Don't get to see many of those.

Comment: Error message should be: *error C4576: a parenthesized type followed by an initializer list is a non-standard explicit type conversion syntax* https://godbolt.org/z/VgRKHC

Comment: You probably want `SDL_Rect{0,0,10,10}`.

Comment: You are inadvertently using a [nonstandard gcc extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Compound-Literals.html#Compound-Literals).

Comment: I apologize for not mentioning what the error code was.  It was error code C4576, which I would provide a link to on the online doc but it has been removed I think.  It goes from C4572 to C4577 in the docs, so that's peculiar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is not valid in ISO C++.  It would be valid in ISO C, and some C++ compilers might support it as an extension.

In C++ you could do any of the following:

- `someFunction( SDL_Rect{0, 0, 10, 10} );`
- `someFunction( {0, 0, 10, 10} );`

To be valid in both languages (not that there is any reason to do this), I think you would need to use a named variable for the argument:

```
SDL_Rect foo = { 0, 0, 10, 10 };
someFunction(foo);
```

or perhaps a preprocessor macro that expands differently based on the language.

Comment: What is the difference between (SDL_Rect) {0, 0, 10, 10} and (SDL_Rect {0, 0, 10, 10}).  Aren't they both casting?

Comment: @K.S.Bilodeau No, the first one is a syntax error.  In a C-style cast, the parenthesized typename must be followed by an expression,  and a braced  list is not an expression

Answer (score 0):

For those who happen to stumble into the same problem as me, the problem was that gcc has an extension that allows for something called compound literals.  Here is an article about it: [Compound Literals Extension GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Compound-Literals.html).  The easiest way to fix it is to cast normally, as shown in the answer above this one!